# DotNetOpenAuth with MVC 4.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dotnetopenauth, asp.net-mvc-4

I have been trying out the DotNetOpenAuth samples with ASP.Net MVC 4 Developer Preview.

I can successfully invoke my Action from my test page, but run into a strange issue because of one line of code:

```
  var request = _openid.CreateRequest(openIdUrl);
  var fetch = new FetchRequest();
  fetch.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email);
  fetch.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Name.First);
  fetch.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Name.Last);
  request.AddExtension(fetch);
  //return RedirectToAction("Login");
  return request.RedirectingResponse.AsActionResult(); // <-- This is the line throwing the error
```

If I comment out the offending line of code and uncomment the one before this, I do not see the runtime error anymore.

So far I have tried:

1) Ensuring that I have the correct redirects:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
    <legacyHMACWarning enabled="0" />
</runtime>
```

2) Have the correct namespaces:

```
using DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Extensions.AttributeExchange;
using DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Extensions;
```

It seems to me that the DotNetOpenAuth dll was compiled against MVC V 1.0.0 and the binding redirect is either not working or the extension method was maybe working against a deprecated method.

MVC Version: 4.0.0.0
DotNetOpenAuth Version: 3.4.7.11121

Any help on getting this working with MVC 4 would be greatly appreciated.
The MVC error screen image is further below:

[Image of Error Screen](http://pictures.sukul.org/Temp/OpenAuthDotNetError.jpg)

**Update**
I found that AsActionResult is the cause of the issue, maybe because the extension method is not compatible with .Net 4.0. I can get the OutgoingWebResponse object from request.RedirectingResponse but do know how to cast it to an ActionResult

Comment: Is your sample code to get OpenId working with MVC4 somewhere I can see. I am running into numerous issues ranging from image paths to JS errors when I invoke the provider button.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears your binding redirects are corrupted.  Notice how System.Web.Mvc appears twice?  Try removing the second one as the first one looks correct.

Yes, DNOA is built against MVC 1.0, and this is by design so that it works against all versions of MVC (given the appropriate redirects).  This is purely an MVC version thing -- not a .NET 4.0 thing.

Comment: You have a really keen eye. Thank you!! I thought I was going crazy.

Comment: Thank you Thank you Thank you :).. I was getting the same issue, for mvc3, this worked for me "<bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>".